# 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, parsing

The code works fine when I added the first row, but then afterwards it throws me

> An exception of type `System.FormatException` occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

I've been staring at this code for quite a while now and cant seem to pinpoint what's the issue that could cause this.

```
protected void OnAddEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridViewPersonal.SelectedDataKey == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        int employeeID = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewEmployee.Rows)
        {
            if (employeeID < int.Parse(row.Cells[0].ToString()))
            {
                employeeID = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].ToString());
            }
        }
        employeeID++;



                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hope that exception is throwing in this line: `int.Parse(row.Cells[0].ToString()` please use `TryParse`  instead for `parse`

Comment: I tried TryParse and its throwing me the same exception

Comment: @un-lucky sorry....

Comment: coool Happy to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the issue is with the conversion, Please take a look into the `foreach`, There you are getting the value of `row.Cells[0].ToString()` sometimes that is `null`, `empty` or some other values which are not convertible to a valid integer, this time you will get `FormatException` as you are getting now. One more thing you are doing wrong there, you are parsing the same value two times, to avoid both of these mistakes you can use `TryParse`, in this case your code will be like this:

```
int employeeID = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewEmployee.Rows)
{
    if (int.TryParse(row.Cells[0].ToString(), out employeeID))
    {
       break;
    }
}
```

**Please note** : I just tried to give you an example usage of `int.TryParse` inside that loop, I don't get the exact process that you are tried with the loop here, In the above example if will break the loop when the first valid conversion executes. you can remove the break if you want to loop through all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when int.parse runs into non-numeric characters. You could use a try catch block to catch the error and just move onto the next row or you could use int.tryparse to check it as you go without the try catch. Here's code with the tryparse:

```
int employeeID = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridViewEmployee.Rows)
{
    string curStr = row.Cells[0].ToString();
    int curID = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(curStr, curID)){
        if (employeeID < curID)
        {
            employeeID = curID);
        }
    }
}
employeeID++;
```

You should probably also use a debugger to step through and observe the cell value as a string before parsing it, which is why I made a separate variable for it. I hit myself over the head hardest (figuratively) when I finally realize that I have been pulling data from the wrong column the whole time.